# using QList<QStringList> to populate a QTableView. When something gets changed in the View, how do I get it back in the data?

Tags: qt, tableview

I have a matrix of data, I simply stored it as a QList of QStringLists, all containing an equal number of QStrings. In this way, the data looks almost like a spreadsheet.

I use a QTableView to present this data to the user:

```
void DialogwitQTableView::setData(QList<QStringList> s)
{
    /* Create the data model */
    // 1. give it some headers
    QStandardItemModel model = new QStandardItemModel(s.count(),25,this); //x Rows and 25 Columns
    model->setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, new QStandardItem(QString("Column 1")));
    model->setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, new QStandardItem(QString("Column 2")));
     // ...
    model->setHorizontalHeaderItem(24, new QStandardItem(QString("Column 25")));

    // 2. populate the model with the data

    for(int i = 0; i < s.count() ; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < s[i].count() ; j++)
            model->setItem(i,j,new QStandardItem(QString(s[i][j])));
    }
    ui->NameOfTheTableView->setModel(model);
}
```

Now, if the user wants to change some of the data, he will just doubleclick in the QTableView in the Dialogbox and edits what he wants.

How do I get that edit also in the data? How can I adapt the QStringList with that new information?

If I search for documentation, I mostly find QTableViews linked to databases, but I don't see how this will work with a simple datastructure in memory. If I go to QtDesigner and click on "go to slots" for the TableView, I also do not see a slot called "datachanged" or anything similar.

Any thoughts? I feel pretty stuck and I am probably overviewing something, any tip is very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that for more complicated cases it's always best to use the abstract classes, more specifically QAbstractTableModel in this case.

Looking at this file, I just replaced Contact with StringList and changed the getters and setters. Check it out:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-addressbook-tablemodel-cpp.html

```
TableModel::TableModel(QObject *parent) : 
    QAbstractTableModel(parent)
{
}

TableModel::TableModel(QList<QStringList> stringLists, QObject *parent) : 
    QAbstractTableModel(parent), 
    stringLists(stringLists)
{
}

int TableModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    Q_UNUSED(parent);
    return stringLists.size();
}

int TableModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    Q_UNUSED(parent);
    return 2; // put the amount of columns here
}

QVariant TableModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (!index.isValid()) return QVariant();

    if (index.row() >= stringLists.size() || index.row() < 0)  return QVariant();

    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole) {
        const auto &strings = stringLists.at(index.row());

        if (index.column() == 0)
            return strings[0];
        else if (index.column() == 1)
            return strings[1];
    }
    return QVariant();
}
QVariant TableModel::headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const
{
    if (role != Qt::DisplayRole)
        return QVariant();

    if (orientation == Qt::Horizontal) {
        switch (section) {
            case 0:
                return tr("String 1");

            case 1:
                return tr("String 2");

            default:
                return QVariant();
        }
    }
    return QVariant();
}

bool TableModel::insertRows(int position, int rows, const QModelIndex &index)
{
    Q_UNUSED(index);
    beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), position, position + rows - 1);

    for (int row = 0; row < rows; ++row)
        stringLists.insert(position, { QString(), QString() });

    endInsertRows();
    return true;
}

bool TableModel::removeRows(int position, int rows, const QModelIndex &index)
{
    Q_UNUSED(index);
    beginRemoveRows(QModelIndex(), position, position + rows - 1);

    for (int row = 0; row < rows; ++row)
        stringLists.removeAt(position);

    endRemoveRows();
    return true;
}
bool TableModel::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role)
{
    if (index.isValid() && role == Qt::EditRole) {
        int row = index.row();

        auto strings = stringLists.at(row);

        if (index.column() == 0)
            strings[0] = value.toString();
        else if (index.column() == 1)
            contact[1] = value.toString();
        else
            return false;

        stringLists.replace(row, contact);
        emit dataChanged(index, index, {role});

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
Qt::ItemFlags TableModel::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if (!index.isValid()) return Qt::ItemIsEnabled;

    return QAbstractTableModel::flags(index) | Qt::ItemIsEditable;
}

QList<QStringList> TableModel::getStringLists() const
{
    return stringLists;
}
```

I also highly recommend that you read this:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/modelview.html

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the doco, a QTableView inherits 6 signals from QAbstractItemView

http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qabstractitemview.html#signals

This class has all sorts of functionality for capturing edits, and edit triggers.

Once you can catch when the data is changed you can recommit it back to your model if you are using an MVC view. I am sure there are a lot of examples.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I am still a bit confused. Does this mean that the signal "entered" is triggered when something got edited in the View? And how do i use an Edit Trigger with it? (sorry for the overload, but it is simply not clear to me at this point)

Comment: entered would be triggered when the cursor goes into a cell, it would call your slot with the index of the cell... You don't need to use an edit-trigger with it. Just catch the necessary signals so you can detect when the data has changed. You might want to look at http://www.archivum.info/qt-interest@trolltech.com/2009-04/00844/(Qt-interest)-EditTriggers-options.html

Answer (score 1):

> If I search for documentation, I mostly find QTableViews linked to
>   databases, but I don't see how this will work with a simple
>   datastructure in memory.

`QTableView` is a part of Qt's [Model/View framework](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/model-view-programming.html). There are bunch of examples of model-views.

> How do I get that edit also in the data? How can I adapt the
>   QStringList with that new information?

At least these solutions exists:

1. You can grab all data from `QStandardItemModel` via `item` method.
2. Connect to `QStandardItemModel::itemChanged` signal.
3. You can make your own model via subclassing (and I suggest to base on `QAbstractTableModel`) and implement several methods (`data`, `setData` + several utility methods).